# Run airflow cli in Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I tried to run airflow test cli in the Google Cloud Composer environment but it does not work.

Basically, I want to run `airflow test` to test a task in the airflow environment. I am following the instruction here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-cli

This is the command I run:

```
gcloud beta composer environments run ENVIRONMENT_NAME test MY_DAG FIRST_TASK 2018-05-05
```

Output:

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.composer.environments.run) unrecognized arguments:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include two hyphens between the Airflow sub-command ("test") and its args. The hyphens direct gcloud to ignore the args that follow and pass them through to the Airflow sub-command.

> gcloud beta composer environments run ENVIRONMENT_NAME test -- MY_DAG FIRST_TASK 2018-05-05

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/composer/environments/run

Comment: But how do you pipe or grep..etc interact with the output after the "--" ?